# Start collabnet's subversion server automatically

Tags: svn, service, ubuntu-14.04, collabnet, svnserve

I have successfully installed CollabNet SVN server on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, but I want to start the subversion server on startup automatically not from web console.

what is the command to do that?

I couldn't find `svnserve` file inside CollabNet's bin folder.

[image]